# Android remove recent call list

Tags: android

How to delete recent call list in Android 1.6, programmaticaly.

I deleted the call log using the URI (content://call_log/calls). It workes fine on 2.o and above version. I am not able to delete recent call list using this URI in 1.6 API level handsets.

Please let me know is there any other URI to fetch Recent Call list and method to remove the recent call list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null);
```

This should work for you. As this is supported [since API level 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html)

Comment: if you wanted to delete a single number use the where clause context.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+"='"+numberToRemove+"'",null);

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the CallLog class, which is part of android.provider.

See more info at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

You should be able to call it using the constructor listed there. Hope that helps!

Comment: I think, you can not directly do this, as it is part of Content Provider.

Comment: @Rajnikant- Its possible and I completed the task.